# java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin

Tags: expo, local-storage, google-play-console

I am getting this error in the last 2 versions I put on the play console, I did not encounter this problem in the previous 4 versions and the difference in the last 2 versions is that I just added local storage, how should I solve this error?

[image: Error Message]

[image: Device Info]

[image: Releases]

I am using react native expo and this is where I use local storage:

[image: Codes]